# Can't find error to not being able to compile into device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I coded some scripts using some assets from the store and when i'm trying to compile the program to the Android phone i'm getting errors on compilation.

I changed SDK versions from 26 to 25, tried running the build on Graddle, Internal and Using Legacy SDK Tools, re built the entire project, updated assets, tried to normal build APK but it still gives out failure.

Error 1:

```
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer& number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean parseDecimal) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Int32.Parse (System.String s, System.IFormatProvider provider) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Convert.ToInt32 (System.String value) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeviceInfo.get_SDKVersion () (at <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeviceInfo.HasSDKSupport (System.Int32 minimumVersion) (at <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+AndroidDeploymentTargetInfo.CheckTargetInternal (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetRequirements targetRequirements) (at <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+AndroidDeploymentTargetInfo.CheckTarget (UnityEditor.DeploymentTargetRequirements targetRequirements) (at <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckDevice.FindCompatibleDevices (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetRequirements targetRequirements, UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetId targetId, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] knownDevices, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckDevice+DeviceInfo]& compatibleDevices) (at <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckDevice.GetTargetDevices (UnityEditor.Android.ADB adb) (at <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckDevice.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PrepareForBuild (UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PrepareForBuild (UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <7cbc688ae1af4105929402a46c6a4414>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.PrepareForBuild (UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:106)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Error 2:

```
Error building Player: FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Error 3:

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
0x0000000141415DE8 (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x000000014141C296 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00000001412FFB1B (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x000000014014325E (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00000001417873BD (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x0000000043145590 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x00000000431451F3 (Mono JIT Code) [DebugLogHandler.cs:10] UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[]) 
0x0000000043144A75 (Mono JIT Code) [Logger.cs:48] UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object) 
0x0000000043144709 (Mono JIT Code) [Debug.bindings.cs:117] UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object) 
0x0000000040DDE863 (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) 
0x0000000040DD601B (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions) 
0x0000000040DD57BB (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:174] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun (bool) 
0x0000000040DAA16B (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:926] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform) 
0x0000000040D587BB (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:809] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings () 
0x0000000040C8A45B (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:411] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI () 
0x00000000485FC8D0 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007FF8B273BE4B (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2809] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FF8B26C1E32 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2919] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FF8B26CB012 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3071] mono_runtime_invoke_checked 
0x00007FF8B26CB7A9 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:5262] mono_runtime_try_invoke_array 
0x00007FF8B26CAFA6 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:5140] mono_runtime_invoke_array_checked 
0x00007FF8B266FED4 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [icall.c:3358] ves_icall_InternalInvoke 
0x000000003C6F64F6 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
0x000000003C6F4F1B (Mono JIT Code) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
0x000000003EF8F56F (Mono JIT Code) System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke (object,object[])
0x0000000040497293 (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:342] UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke (string,object) 
0x00000000404970F3 (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:337] UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke (string) 
0x0000000040C88463 (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:130] UnityEditor.HostView:OldOnGUI () 
0x00000000409B13DC (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:244] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool) 
0x000000004098DA6B (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:440] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect) 
0x0000000040B148D3 (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:421] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event) 
0x000000004048E2FB (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:401] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase) 
0x000000003F4A47E4 (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatcher.cs:516] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IPanel) 
0x000000003F1BF0FB (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatcher.cs:308] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.DispatchMode) 
0x000000003F1BEBC3 (Mono JIT Code) [Panel.cs:177] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.DispatchMode) 
0x000000004091F653 (Mono JIT Code) [UIElementsUtility.cs:248] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel) 
0x000000004094F8FB (Mono JIT Code) [UIElementsUtility.cs:68] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr) 
0x000000004094F264 (Mono JIT Code) [GUIUtility.cs:179] UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr) 
0x000000004094F483 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_bool_int_intptr (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007FF8B273BE4B (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2809] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FF8B26C1E32 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2919] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FF8B26CAE3F (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2966] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x0000000140C02DDA (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x0000000140BF33EA (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x0000000140BED44A (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<bool>
0x000000014042E60C (Unity) Scripting::UnityEngine::GUIUtilityProxy::ProcessEvent
0x000000014129171C (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
0x000000014147ABA0 (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent
0x000000014129162C (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEvent
0x000000014147C23C (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages
0x00000001414720CF (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc
0x00007FF901476D41 (USER32) CallWindowProcW
0x00007FF901476713 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
0x000000014149892F (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x000000014149A426 (Unity) WinMain
0x000000014247F7EA (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007FF9011A4034 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FF901873691 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

Error 4:

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00234] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96 
0x0000000141415DE8 (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x000000014141C296 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00000001412FFB1B (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x000000014014325E (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00000001417873BD (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x0000000043145590 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x00000000431451F3 (Mono JIT Code) [DebugLogHandler.cs:10] UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[]) 
0x0000000043144A75 (Mono JIT Code) [Logger.cs:48] UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object) 
0x0000000043144709 (Mono JIT Code) [Debug.bindings.cs:117] UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object) 
0x0000000040DD619B (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:102] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions) 
0x0000000040DD57BB (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:174] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun (bool) 
0x0000000040DAA16B (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:926] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform) 
0x0000000040D587BB (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:809] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings () 
0x0000000040C8A45B (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:411] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI () 
0x00000000485FC8D0 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007FF8B273BE4B (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2809] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FF8B26C1E32 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2919] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FF8B26CB012 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3071] mono_runtime_invoke_checked 
0x00007FF8B26CB7A9 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:5262] mono_runtime_try_invoke_array 
0x00007FF8B26CAFA6 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:5140] mono_runtime_invoke_array_checked 
0x00007FF8B266FED4 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [icall.c:3358] ves_icall_InternalInvoke 
0x000000003C6F64F6 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
0x000000003C6F4F1B (Mono JIT Code) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
0x000000003EF8F56F (Mono JIT Code) System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke (object,object[])
0x0000000040497293 (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:342] UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke (string,object) 
0x00000000404970F3 (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:337] UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke (string) 
0x0000000040C88463 (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:130] UnityEditor.HostView:OldOnGUI () 
0x00000000409B13DC (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:244] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool) 
0x000000004098DA6B (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:440] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect) 
0x0000000040B148D3 (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:421] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event) 
0x000000004048E2FB (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:401] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase) 
0x000000003F4A47E4 (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatcher.cs:516] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IPanel) 
0x000000003F1BF0FB (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatcher.cs:308] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.DispatchMode) 
0x000000003F1BEBC3 (Mono JIT Code) [Panel.cs:177] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.DispatchMode) 
0x000000004091F653 (Mono JIT Code) [UIElementsUtility.cs:248] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel) 
0x000000004094F8FB (Mono JIT Code) [UIElementsUtility.cs:68] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr) 
0x000000004094F264 (Mono JIT Code) [GUIUtility.cs:179] UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr) 
0x000000004094F483 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_bool_int_intptr (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007FF8B273BE4B (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2809] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FF8B26C1E32 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2919] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FF8B26CAE3F (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2966] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x0000000140C02DDA (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x0000000140BF33EA (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x0000000140BED44A (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<bool>
0x000000014042E60C (Unity) Scripting::UnityEngine::GUIUtilityProxy::ProcessEvent
0x000000014129171C (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
0x000000014147ABA0 (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent
0x000000014129162C (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEvent
0x000000014147C23C (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages
0x00000001414720CF (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc
0x00007FF901476D41 (USER32) CallWindowProcW
0x00007FF901476713 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
0x000000014149892F (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x000000014149A426 (Unity) WinMain
0x000000014247F7EA (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007FF9011A4034 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FF901873691 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

My expected output is to be able to compile the APK into the phone for testing controls and further developing.

Comment: Could you show any code, please? It seems like if you have some edit text with some entry pattern and the app try to check the validation of the input.

Comment: @AlbertoSáezVela doesn't sound like OP can do that. Looks like an internal Unity call during the build trying to use `int.Parse` somewhere to find the API version but uses a malformed string value.

Comment: I was able to work this around and compile it into an APK, i was calling the AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath as i want to load images into a Canvas > RawImage dynamically, so removed this lines and it compiled, i still can't "Build and Play" but i can atleast continue working on it until i dip my self into the image issue.